# Why my question gets so many downvotes? Is it off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question
[picture on the academic page of a PhD candidate seeking postdoc](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58955/picture-on-the-academic-page-of-a-phd-candidate-seeking-postdoc)

and it got many downvotes soon, without any comment.
I don't know the reason.
Is my question  off-topic on Academic Exchange?

Comment: I guess it is because I didn't specify I am a male.

Answer (score 5):

I think the line "people won't see my nips anyway" is just the sort of throwaway line that doesn't add to the post, and is just the sort of thing we've seen from previous posters who just posted silliness in order to prompt any kind of reaction.

If you don't want to be mistaken for one of those type of posters, don't write like them

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but this plus the somewhat contrived "No good shirted pictures exist anywhere" implied in the post is...odd.

Comment: @Fomite I've known people with stranger relationships to cameras.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why it's picking up down votes: I thought it was a pretty good question and so I voted it up and answered it.

I will note, however, that somebody flagged it for possible closure as "primarily opinion based", so it may be that some people are thinking it might be too much of a personal choice.  From my answer, however, you will see that I think there *is* a fairly general approach that can be taken to this sort of question.

Comment: Thanks. I will leave the question there, unless many people vote for close it.
And thank you again for the minor clean ups of my question.

Comment: @user565739 And now it seems we're seeing another phenomena that I expected as well: with a solid answer, the question is getting more upvotes.

Comment: And now it has more than 1K views...Good, but I am confused why it went bad at the beginning, but fine.

Comment: @user565739 Keep in mind that with a small number of votes, something "going bad at the beginning" is actually only a few people.